# How to load data into Phoenix from Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-phoenix

Hive has a [HBase integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration). Given that, would it be possible to insert into a Phoenix table from hive? (as a bulk load/insert overwrite) What about compound primary keys? Can we generate them in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately Hive HBase integration does not enable loading data into Phoenix table. Also, (as per my experience) support for composite rowkeys for HBase integration is not comprehensive. For example: Hive cannot support a composite keys containing Integer,String, BigDecimal.

You can either use [Phoenix-mr](http://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_mr.html) integration or [Phoenix-Pig](http://phoenix.apache.org/pig_integration.html) integration. Phoenix also has a csv bulk loader.